# Visual studio 2010 C++ project link failure: fatal error LINK1171: unable to load ole32.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, managed, visual-c++-6

I'm trying to build a VC++ project. It was working fine without errors but after adding some classes which call .Net Framework dlls by below directives:

```
#using "mscorlib.dll"
#using #System.dll"
#using "System.Data.dll"
#using "System.Xml.dll"
```

And setting `Use Managed Extensions` to `Yes`, the project does not build successfully and reports:

> fatal error LINK1171: unable to load ole32.dll

during the link process.

I never used `ole32.dll` and compiler does not show where does it need this dll.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, it is alink.dll that has a dependency on it, used when you link managed code.  It is not unusual for c:\windows\syswow64\ole32.dll to be vulnerable to a Win95 era uninstaller.  You'll need to get this machine fixed, best to ask at superuser.com

Comment: @HansPassant So how can I add 'ole32.dll' to project dependencies so I do not face this error anymore during the linking process?